# Rust not properly reading integer input

Tags: rust

I'm trying to test out my Rust skills with a simple program that reads multiple integers from a single line of input. It compiles correctly, but unfortunately when it receives the input of `1 2 3`, it panics, saying that the input wasn't a valid integer. Can someone please explain the reason for this, and also provide an explanation as to how I can fix my program?

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut string = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut string);

    let int_vec: Vec<u32> = string.split(" ")
        .map(|x| x.parse::<u32>().expect("Not an integer!"))
        .collect();

     for i in (0..int_vec.len()).rev() {
         print!("{} ", int_vec[i]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Dogberts answer... it might be helpful to see how you might be able to debug this sort of issue with an iterator yourself in future.

The `Iterator` trait exposes an `inspect` function that you can use to inspect each item. Converting your code to use `inspect` both before and after each map results in:

```
let int_vec: Vec<u32> = string.split(" ")
.inspect(|x| println!("About to parse: {:?}", x))
.map(|x| {
    x.parse::<u32>()
        .expect("Not an integer!")
})
.inspect(|x| println!("Parsed {:?} successfully!", x))
.collect();
```

Outputs:

```
1 2 3
About to parse: "1"
Parsed 1 successfully!
About to parse: "2"
Parsed 2 successfully!
About to parse: "3\n"

thread '<main>' panicked at 'Not an integer!...
```

Notice what its attempting to parse when it gets to the number 3.

Of course, you can inspect `string` all by itself. `inspect` is handy though for when iterators are involved.

Comment: TIL: there is an `inspect` function! That's very useful indeed to peek in the middle of the stream.

Answer (score 8):

This is because `io::stdin().read_line(&mut String)` also adds a trailing newline character to the string, which causes the last str after splitting with `" "` to be `"123\n"`, which is not a valid integer. You can use `str::trim()` for this:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut string = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut string);

    let int_vec: Vec<u32> = string.trim()
        .split(" ")
        .map(|x| {
            x.parse::<u32>()
                .expect("Not an integer!")
        })
        .collect();

    for i in (0..int_vec.len()).rev() {
        print!("{} ", int_vec[i]);
    }
}
```

With this change, the program works:

```
$ ./a
1 2 3
3 2 1
```

Also, you can simplify your `for` loop:

```
for i in int_vec.iter().rev() {
    print!("{} ", i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I originally tried to trim the string, but forgot that the function returns a new string, it doesn't manipulate the old one. Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: @KavanaughDempsey *the function returns a new string* — just to be specific, `trim` returns a new *string slice* (`&str`); this refers to the existing string and doesn't allocate a new *owned string* (`String`).

Comment: Instead of `.trim().split(" ")` you might also consider `.split_whitespace()`.

Answer (score 5):

You ran into the old problem of the terminating line-ending. Let's try putting

```
println!("{:?}", string);
```

in the third line of your code. For the input `1 2 3` it will print (on Windows):

```
"1 2 3\r\n"
```

So at some point you are trying to parse `"3\r\n"` as integer, which obviously fails. One easy way to remove trailing and leading whitespace from a string is to use [`trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim). This works:

```
let int_vec: Vec<_> = string.trim().split(" ")
    .map(|x| x.parse::<u32>().expect("Not an integer!"))
    .collect();
```