# How to create a file using user`s input in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to create file using keyboard input, but the created file's name has unnecessary symbols.

```
use std::io;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut filesname = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut filesname)
        .ok()
        .expect("cant read string");
    filecreate(&filesname);
}

fn filecreate(path: &str) {
    let f = File::create(path);
    println!("Ok, file {} was created.", path);
}
```

Using this code I wrote `"foo.txt"`, but my  file manager shows this file as "'foo.txt'$'\n'".
I can't figure out what I have to do with the user's input.

Comment: `read_line()` also reads the newline; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725783/rust-not-properly-reading-integer-input) for the same issue.

Comment: The only extra symbol is `\n` which is printed by `ls` as `$'\n'`. In bash, newlines can be represented inside single quotes if the single quotes are preceded by `$`, and strings can be concatenated by simply placing them beside each other. That is, `$'foo\n'` == `'foo'$'\n'` == `'fo'$'o\n'` == `'f''o''o'$'\n'` == `'f'oo$'\n'`. So just trim the final newline off!